# Problem installing HP Wireless Printer

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, printing, hp

I have an HP5510 Wireless printer that I have been using for a year or two.

I have no problems connecting to it with both my current laptop running 12.04LTS and my wife's Windows 8 HP laptop.  I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 as a dual boot on my wife's HP with minimal hassle.  However, I simply cannot get this bloody printer to work with 13.10!

I have tried simply adding the printer through the Printers section of Ubuntu.  It is unable to find the printer when it scans.  When I manually enter the IP address of the printer it then finds the printer and recognizes it as an HP5510-d series printer.  I click ADD and it goes to the next screen where it starts to install, pauses for roughly three seconds, and then pops up a dialogue saying "Unable to install printer" with no further explanation.

I've done this maybe a dozen times with the same result.  I downloaded and installed the current hplip, but that did not help at all.  I even downloaded and installed the HpLip GUI tool.  Using that tool I try to add a wireless printer but it insists that I first cable to the printer.  Nope.  I've had this printer for quite some time.  I'm sure it came with a cable but... nope.  And why would I need a USB cable to connect to a printer that is already online!  Isn't that just for initializing the printer?!?!?

Anyway, I appear to be stuck.  Any suggestions that don't involve purchasing a USB cable simply to connect to Ubuntu for 90 seconds in order to install a printer that it is able to connect with wirelessly when I give it the IP address?  I've spent years telling my wife how much easier everything is in Ubuntu as opposed to Windows, and right now this is killing my credibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scan to work on some HP printers you need to install the some special driver provided by HP - which I can remember the name of right now.

This is easily done by running the following in the terminal

```
sudo hp-setup
```

If the printer is on a personal network then choose the 2nd option so that a USB cable is not needed.

Comment: And I'll just sit here and wallow in my idiocy....   I had run hp-setup and it failed to find the printer via scan under the second option, which is why I moved on to the third which required a cable.  I hadn't even noticed the Advanced Options, which allowed me to manually input the IP address of the printer.   Well done, sire.

Answer (score 0):

`hplip` is the setup software for HP printers and scanners. `hplip toolbox` is the GUI.

Both are in the repos.